# How to loop through a foreach until X is found, if not found, look for Y

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, search, foreach

Sorry if this is a duplicate, I can't figure out what to search for to find the answer.

I have a foreach loop, and in that loop, I'm attempting to test if (A == B). Then once found I break the loop. If (A != B) in an iteration, I test if (X == Y).

My problem is that if (X == Y) is found to be true first, the loop breaks before if (A == B) can be tested.

Is there a better way to accomplish this task?

```
$variable[1] = ['A' => 'n', 'X' => 'n'];
$variable[2] = ['A' => 'n', 'X' => 'Y'];
$variable[3] = ['A' => 'B', 'X' => 'n'];

$test = 'B';

foreach ($variable as $value) {

    if($value['A'] == $test || $value['X'] == "Y") {
        echo 'The results: ' . $value['A'];
        break;
    }

}

// The results for $variable[2] are returned. I need the results for $variable[3] to be returned.
```

I did have an else statement which worked fine, but I was having to duplicate the output.

Thanks in advance!

The code above is a simplified version of what I'm working on. Here's the code I'm working actually working on.

```
foreach ($product_xml->products->product_styles as $style => $attribute) {
    if(isset($_GET['color']) && $attribute['color'] == $color_selected || $attribute['is_default'] == "1") {
        foreach ($attribute as $value){
            $imgURL = (string)$value['imgurl'];
            $thumburl = (string)$value['thumburl'];
            $thumburl_array[(string)$value['side']] = (string)$value['thumburl'];
            if (in_array($imgURL, $values)){continue;}
            else{
                array_push($values, $imgURL);
                $imgURL = str_replace("REPLACE_DOMAIN_WITH",IDEQ_INKSOFTAPI_URL_SECURE,$imgURL );
                $thumburl = str_replace("REPLACE_DOMAIN_WITH",IDEQ_INKSOFTAPI_URL_SECURE,$thumburl );
                $thumburl = str_replace("150.png","500.png",$thumburl );
                echo '<img src="'.$imgURL.'" class="pic'.$counter.'" title="'.$value['name'].'">';
                $counter++;
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a for loop, reset `$i` to 0 on last loop, toggle flag, then do Y check

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, James. I've submitted an answer based on your response. The solution works 100%. The only improvement I'd like to make would be to not have to loop twice to perform multiple tests.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based off of the response from [James Lalor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4022234/james-lalor) I've come to this solution. If anyone sees a better/more optimal way of handling this, I'd love to hear!

```
$counter = 1;
$values = array();
$thumburl_array = array();
$found = false;
$find_default = false;
$style_count = count($product_xml->products->product_styles);

for ($i=0; $i < $style_count; $i++) { 
    if (isset($_GET['color']) && $product_xml->products->product_styles[$i]['color'] == $color_selected) {
        $found = true;
    } elseif (!$found && !$find_default && $i == $style_count - 1) {
        $find_default = true;
        $i = 0;
    }

    if ($find_default && $product_xml->products->product_styles[$i]['is_default'] == '1') {
        $found = true;
    }

    if ($found) {
        foreach ($product_xml->products->product_styles[$i] as $value){
            $imgURL = (string)$value['imgurl'];
            $thumburl = (string)$value['thumburl'];
            $thumburl_array[(string)$value['side']] = (string)$value['thumburl'];
            if (in_array($imgURL, $values)){continue;}
            else{
                array_push($values, $imgURL);
                $imgURL = str_replace("REPLACE_DOMAIN_WITH",IDEQ_INKSOFTAPI_URL_SECURE,$imgURL );
                $thumburl = str_replace("REPLACE_DOMAIN_WITH",IDEQ_INKSOFTAPI_URL_SECURE,$thumburl );
                $thumburl = str_replace("150.png","500.png",$thumburl );
                echo '<img src="'.$imgURL.'" class="pic'.$counter.'" title="'.$value['name'].'">';
                $counter++;
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Simplified version

```
$variable[] = ['A' => 'n', 'X' => 'n', 'result' => 'do'];
$variable[] = ['A' => 'n', 'X' => 'Y', 'result' => 're'];
$variable[] = ['A' => 'B', 'X' => 'n', 'result' => 'mi'];

$found = false;
$find_default = false;
$count = count($variable);

$test = 'B';

for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) { 
    if ($variable[$i]['A'] == $test) {
        $found = true;
    } elseif (!$found && !$find_default && $i == $count - 1) {
        $find_default = true;
        $i = 0;
        continue;
    }

    if ($find_default && $variable[$i]['X'] == 'Y') {
        $found = true;
    }

    if ($found) {
        echo "Resulsts: " . $variable[$i]['result'];
        break;
    }
}
```

Thank you all for your feedback, much appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: See my answer, that is far better than any looping

Comment: I'll look into this now and get back to you.

Comment: Just to clearify, the method you use, suggested by James in comments is the worst of all ideas. That means you loop the full array twice. The other two looping answers you have here loop the array once. My answer does not loop at all.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not too excited about looping twice. I'm trying to figure out how to implement your suggestion. I'm close, but not quite there.

Answer (score 2):

Use a temporary variable and move the `echo` to after the `foreach`.

```
$variable[1] = ['A' => 'n', 'X' => 'n'];
$variable[2] = ['A' => 'n', 'X' => 'Y'];
$variable[3] = ['A' => 'B', 'X' => 'n'];

$test = 'B';
$output = null;

foreach ($variable as $value) {

    if($value['A'] == $test) {
        $output = $value['A'];
        break;
    } else if ($output == null && $value['X'] == "Y") {
        $output = $value['X'];
    }
}

echo 'The results: ' . $output;
```

Comment: Maybe you meant to echo `$output` at the end?

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I have to perform some additional functionality once found though instead just an echo. I simplified the code in my question to hopefully make it easier to analyze. I'm going to add the code I'm actually working on now for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approximation with a function:

```
function search($variable, $test){
    $alternative = null;

    foreach($variable as $value){
        if($value['A'] == $test){
            return $value['A'];
        }
        if($value['X'] == 'Y' && $alternative === null){
            $alternative = $value['A'];
        }
    }

    return $alternative;
}
```

It will return first coincidence on A and if not found, first coincidence on X.

This way you only loop through **foreach** once.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping you can use array_column to isolate one column of the array A or X.
Then use in_array to see if you find the $test in the array.

```
$test = 'B';
$test2 = 'Y';

If(in_array($test, array_column($variable, "A"))){
    Echo $test . " Found in A";
}Else if(in_array($test2, array_column($variable, "X"))){
    Echo $test2 . " Found in B";
}else{
    Echo "none found";
}
```

https://3v4l.org/dv7Yp

Comment: I can't have three separate echoes. The echoes are just placeholders. There's actually some additional functionality that has to happen that I don't want to repeat.

Comment: @Josh This is what you had in your question. If you don't like that then you should not have posted it in your question. If you want to mask your real code or data it's your problem to implement it later. If you had given us the real code to start with you would have gotten an answer you could use directly.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback. I was hopeing simplifying it would make it easier to analyze.